# How to make an image act as hyperlink in pdf using pdfbox

Tags: pdfbox

I want to add a "move up" **image**, clicking on which should take me to the first page of the pdf. I want to do this on click of an image and not on text or rectangle. Please help me with this.

Comment: It's like with text but your rectangle must have same position + size of the image.

Comment: Yeah i did that only... was wondering if there was another more simple and direct way... thanks anyways!!! :)

Comment: No there isn't. PDFBox is rather low level. If you want comfort, use itext.